# What efficiency is the AsynchronousFileChannel on windows os?

Tags: java, aio

I'm learning about the Java NIO.2 API these days, I did a test to compare the efficiency between AIO and the Standard IO,The test is to write a 2000M file.Here is the code.

The standard way:

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(tmp);
byte[] byteArr = new byte[1024 * 1024];
for (int i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024; i++) {
    byteArr[i] = 1;
}
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
while (length -- > 0) {
    output.write(byteArr);
}
System.out.println("taking time:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");
```

the result is `taking time:10392ms`

The AIO way:

```
AsynchronousFileChannel afc   = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(path, WRITE, CREATE);
List<Future<Integer>> results = new ArrayList<>();
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 1024);
buf.clear();
for (int j = 0; j < 1024 * 1024; j++) {
    buf.put((byte) 1);
}
buf.flip();
buf.mark();
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i ++) {
    buf.reset();
    results.add(afc.write(buf, i * 1024 *1024));
}
for(Future<Integer> future : results) {
    future.get();
}
System.out.println("taking time:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");
```

the result is `taking time:15652ms`

I think,in the second case,the program submits 2000 writing requests to the OS. the OS will run the IO operation with it's own thread pool. in other words,`thread pool size` IO operations will execute concurrently. it shoud be faster in the second case. But the fact is exactly the opposite,Why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Before the program submit writing requests,the file is locked until the end of the writing operation.In other word,only one operation is allowed by the `AsynchronousFileChannel` at the same time.So multi-thread is invalid.

Comment: The file is not locked. The *write operation* might be blocked, or the thread pool might enforce sequential execution of operations on the same file, or the operating system might sequentialize them: and the disk controller will *certainly* sequentialize them.